# Restarting rsyslog for zimbra servers

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rsyslog, zimbra

I want to forward my zimbra.log to my log collector server. But Im quite worried about restarting rsyslog process because im not sure if it will affect the zimbra mta itself.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the system logger daemon shouldn't have any negative impact on the system or applications. I've reconfigured rsyslog/syslog-ng for remote UDP sending of logs on plenty of servers (including a small Zimbra installation) during production hours, along with service restarts, and I've never had any issues.

Even if syslog was mis-configured/down for a while, nothing bad happened.

However, one cannot say for sure that there will be absolutley no impact on Zimbra's MTA - just to be safe, think about making the change during your maintenance window - shut down Zimbra services, reconfigure rsyslog, and get them back up.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I actually feel the same way. I applied a lot of rsyslog changes on most of my servers except my mail server. But I already tested restarting rsyslog on my staging zimbra architecture and all is well.